# CSS and JQuery not always loading

Tags: jquery, css, hosting, html

Guys I have a big website that I am making and testing each page on it on a free hosting with a free subdomain.
The problem here is that my website sometimes doesn't load the full css file and need me to refresh this happens only a few times on different computers not on the same computer twice also same thing happens with my JQuery file.
And by the way my website have 0 error and optimized very good and it is very fast too.
Is that from the free hosting or something?

Comment: please write code what have you tried.

Comment: its not a problem code thats why i didn't write it

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the free host.

Comment: Strange but difficult to resolve without code and site

Comment: it wont be good if i posted all my html,css and jquery code its very long :D
but do you know sometimes u go for a website and find the web page didnt load good so u press refresh to fix that.. that happens more in my free web hosting website